# Power BI Table Relationship

Tags: database, database-design, powerbi, relationship

I am trying to create two relationships between tables in Power BI.  I have a table (Observations) that contains an employee_id and a supervisor_id  that I am trying to connect to my Contact table.
I need to look up the employee information in the Contact table by using employee_id in the Observation table and also look up the supervisor information in the Contact table using the supervisor_id in the Observation table.

```
              Contact Table                                  Observation Table
           ===================                               =================
Employee_ID     Name           Position             Observation_ID    Employee_ID    Supervisor_ID
---------------------------------------             ----------------------------------------------
123             John Doe       employee             1                123             321
321             Harvey Sample  supervisor           2                456             654
456             Mickey Mouse   employee             3                456             654
654             Donald Duck    supervisor           4                123             321
```

Comment: Please table definitions for the relevant tables.  You will have to learn both the framework and the underlying database.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to create two relationships between the observation and contact table:

1. Create a relationship between Observation Table(Employee_ID) and Contact Table(Employee_ID). The Cardinality should be many to one, and set this relationship as active.
2. Create a relationship between Observation Table(Supervisor_ID) and Contact Table(Employee_ID). The Cardinality should be many to one, and set this relationship as inactive.

[create an inactive relationship Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PnSG.png)

You will then need to use the DAX USERELATIONSHIP function when you want to use the inactive relationship in a formula. Here is a detailed explanation of how to use USERELATIONSHIP: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/userelationship-in-calculated-columns/

Alternatively, you can duplicate the contact table and use one copy for the Employee_ID relationship and the other for the Supervisor_ID relationship. Which option is best will depend on your use case.